# Why were the arch-enemies of the Kong family replaced?

Tags: video-games, continuity, donkey-kong

In *Donkey Kong Country Returns* and its sequels, the Kremlings were replaced in favour of the Tikis, which completely new to the series. Personally, I didn't think they fitted into the DK-universe very well -- I liked my Kremlings.

Anyway, is there some official explanation for this?

Comment: Cold war ended? :)

Comment: @DVK: Close; Developer changed from Rare to Retro, but I still don't see a good reason.

Comment: When did that happen?

Comment: @DVK: IIRC, *Returns* was the first DK country developed by Retro Studios and not by Rare.

Comment: 1994 was Country. As I said, Cold War over (1993, for arguments' sake), Kremlin's no longer a good root for a villain in new PC world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any official reason for the Kremlings' absence, but I would guess it just has to do with changing times. The most recent DK games released before DKCR involved musical instruments. Nintendo and Retro probably wanted to tie that into DKCR, which is why most of the Tikis resemble instruments. I'd also say Nintendo and Retro probably decided they didn't just want to make another version of DKC and do exactly what Rare did.

As for what will happen in the future (I miss the Kremlings too), the Tikis have since appeared in other games (most recent being Mario Kart 7, which came out in 2011). The Kremlings, on the other hand, haven't appeared in a Nintendo game since 2008.

Comment: It's been a long time, but King K. Rool appeared on [*Super Smash Bros. Ultimate*](https://www.ssbwiki.com/King_K._Rool_(SSBU))